# Why am I getting the wrong output while using str.replace()?

Tags: javascript, string, list, replace

My code has an index value that points to a character in a string and I have to replace all the instances of that character with the previous value and the next value alternatively except the value of the given index character. Below is my code to implement this:

```
function replaceChar(string,idx){
    
    a = string[idx]
    b= []
    pre_val = string[idx - 1] 
    post_val = string[idx + 1]
    for(let i=0; i< string.length ; i++){
        if(i==idx){
            continue
        }
        if (string[i]===a){
            b.push(i)
        }
    }
    for(i=0; i<b.length; i++){
        if (i%2==0){
            string = string.replace( string[b[i]],pre_val)
        }
        if (i%2==1){
            string = string.replace(string[b[i]],post_val)
        }
    }
    return string
}
```

The input given is:

```
console.log(replaceChar('Baddy',2))
```

The preferred output is:

```
Baday
```

What I get is:

```
Baady


string = string.replace( string[b[i]],pre_val)
```

=> The value of b[i] in the above statement is 3 and so string[3] should be replaced with a (the previous value) and the output should be Baday. Not sure what is wrong.

Comment: `string.replace()` replaces the first match of `string[b[i]]`. If there are earlier matches, it won't replace the one at index `i`.

Comment: Hi, I am not sure what previous values? Doesn't string[3] directly go to 4th value in the string? b has only [3] as the element and so it would be string[3] right

Comment: Not if there are multiple copies of the same character in `string`.

Comment: If `string = ="aabbb"`, `string[3] == "b"`, so `string.replace(string[3], something)` will replace the `b` at `string[2]`, not the `b` at `string[3]`.

Comment: pre_val = 'a' , string = 'aabbb' , string.replace(string[3], a) . How does it matter what comes before when I'm changing only the value at index 3, sorry I don't understand. Thanks for the reply though.

Comment: When you call a function, it doesn't know what variable you used for the parameter. It just gets the string `b`, it doesn't know that it came from index 3.

Comment: Got it now, string[3] becomes 'b' so it replaces the first 'b' it finds. Thanks a lot

Comment: Yes, now you get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to replace a character at a certain index and you are doing multiple replacements (potentially) you can use an array instead (temporarily):

```
let tmp = string.split(''); //from string into array
for(let i = 0; i<b.length; i++){
    if (i%2==0){
        tmp[b[i]] = pre_val;
    }
    if (i%2==1){
        tmp[b[i]] = post_val;
    }
}
return tmp.join('') //back into a string
```

Also, you need to declare your other variables correctly.

```
    let a = string[idx]
    let b = []
    let pre_val = string[idx - 1] 
    let post_val = string[idx + 1]
```